# Fatal Error Fatal error: Call to a member function getCategorylist() in .phtml file

Tags: module, fatal-error, magento1.9.2.4

I Created one custom module and I want to fetch data from the system.xml file which is created in my module. so for fetching that data I create Model, Block and also .phtml file. But I get the Fatal error.
Here is my `Model File`.

```
<?php

class Vrinsoft_Productlist_Model_Categorylist extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {
  public function getCategorylist() {
    echo "harshil";exit;     
    $categorylist=Mage::getStoreConfig('productlist/section_two/custom_field_nine');
    $result=explode(",",$categorylist);
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');

    foreach($result as $value )
    {
        $val=$category->load($value);   

        $productCollection = $val->getProductCollection();
        $productCollection
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addUrlRewrite();
    }
}
```

Here is `Block File.`

```
<?php
class Vrinsoft_Productlist_Block_Categorylist extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
  public function getCategorylist() 
    {
    echo "block";exit       
        $arr_products = array();
            $products = Mage::getModel("productlist/productlist")­->getCategorylist();

        foreach ($products as $product) 
        {
              $arr_products[] = array(
            'id' => $product-­>getId(),
            'name' => $product­->getName(),
            'url' => $product­->getProductUrl(),
            'image'=>$product­->getImageUrl(),
              );
            }

        return $arr_products;      
    }
}
```

Here is my `.phtml file`

```
<?php 

$products = $this­->getCategorylist();
foreach($products as $product) { ?>
      <div>
        <a href="<?php echo $product['url'] ?>"><?php echo $product['name'] ?></a>
      </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

And Here is my `config.xml file`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vrinsoft_Productlist>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Vrinsoft_Productlist>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
          <productlist>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Vrinsoft_Productlist</module>
          <frontName>productlist</frontName>
        </args>
          </productlist>
        </routers>
        <layout>
           <updates>
                <test>
                     <file>productlist.xml</file>
                 </test>
            </updates>
        </layout>
      </frontend>
    <global>
    <blocks>
        <productlist>
            <class>Vrinsoft_Productlist_Block</class>
        </productlist>
    </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <productlist>
                <class>Vrinsoft_Productlist_Helper</class>
            </productlist>
        </helpers>
        <models>
             <productlist>
                <class>Vrinsoft_Productlist_Model</class>
             </productlist>
        </models>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <system>
                            <children>
                                <config>
                                    <children>
                                        <productlist>
                                            <title>Product Configuration Section</title>
                                        </productlist>
                                    </children>
                                </config>
                            </children>
                        </system>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

so help me out for this problem. Any kind of help will appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You code seems wrong,in a case.

You have try get product collection of your configuration selected categories.

**You need to modify code at your model class Model File**

```
<?php
class Vrinsoft_Productlist_Model_Categorylist extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract {
  public function getCategorylist() {
    echo "harshil";exit;     
    $categorylist=Mage::getStoreConfig('productlist/section_two/custom_field_nine');
    $result=explode(",",$categorylist);
    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->joinField(
        'category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 
        'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left'
        )->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
        array('finset' => $result),
        ))
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds())
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addUrlRewrite();
    return $productCollection;
    }
}
```